# The variance of an arrival process with shifted exponential interval

Tags: probability, exponential-function

Here we have a arrival process. The inter-arrival time follows a shifted negative exponential distribution as:

$f(t)=e^{−\lambda(t−\theta)}$

How to derive the variance of the number of arrivals in time period of T?

Comment: What do you think is the expected number and why?